# Document Update Causing Error Involving Index Mapping Error

Tags: elasticsearch

Setup: Elasticsearch Version 6.3 hosted via AWS Elasticsearch Service

I have a process that is querying documents out of the cluster, analyzing them, then creating a set of bulk updates based on the analysis. These updates are in the form of:

```
POST index/_doc/docId/update
{
    "doc": {
        "width": 5,
        "height": 10
    }
}
```

While running the program, I occasionally see this error in my logs:

```
[o.e.i.c.IndicesClusterStateService] [<nodeId>] [[<indexName>][0]] marking and sending shard failed due to [failed to update mapping for index]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [depth] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [depth] has different [similarity]]
```

This is extremely confusing for a few reasons:

1. I'm NOT updating index mappings, I'm just updating documents.
2. The fields I'm updating (height, width) are not what's being complained about in the error (depth).

Anyone have any experience with this issue or how it might be caused by document updates?

Comment: Not an easy case. Can you verify some basics: do your indices mappings are dyamic:strict. Sometimes we can have this kind of issues if historical indices don't exactly have the same mapping as the last one. Can you verify that all you sent data are integer. (if you have float or array or any non legacy value lost in your dataset, you could have some issues)

Comment: `dynamic.strict` is false for all indices involved. The data is the example was sanitized before posting. In reality, I'm updating documents with 2 integer arrays, and the field the error is complaining about is a text field.